# Stop the edit dialog from showing after uploading new file to document library

Tags: document-library

For SharePoint 2010

How can I stop the edit dialog from showing after uploading new file to document library?

My document library has some additional fields which I don't want the user to amend when a new file is uploaded; they are showing on this edit dialog.

I have a workflow in place that captures data for these fields at a later point in time.

Perhaps its easier to hide the extra fields from the edit dialog when the file is uploaded?

But I still want to be able to display the fields in the list and webpart views.

Many thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of stopping it, go to the library, click on the library ribbon tab and then on the right you should see Forms and you can change the edit or display forms there. You can also do this from SharePoint Designer. Since it is a document library, unfortunately, the use of InfoPath to customize the form is not supported here.

Comment: The only option I see is "Form Web Parts". It brings up a view of the edit dialog but I don't how you can remove fields. Is there a way to export the web part? Then change it then upload it again?

Comment: No, but you could also open the site in SharePoint Designer and make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Understand. If you upload only one new document, then Edit form is opened. User is able to edit metadata and by the button OK save the changes. But if there is a workflow on new item created, when user saves the changes, he gets error, because workflow made the changes instead. 
If you want not to be the Edit form opened right after upload one document into library, make sure that there is no any field as required. Except file name of course. If there is not, then after upload document, you don't get the Edit form.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar request for SharePoint Online in which user wanted to disable / suppress a popup after uploading single file through drag n drop.

This script has been refactored from [Drag and Drop Documents to apply Metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata/144824)

```
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeOut = 10000;
    function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
        if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
            _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
            console.log('Edit Form Disabled');
        } else if (maxTimeOut > 0) {
            maxTimeOut -= 100;
            setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
        }

    }
    setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


    function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
        try {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
            var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
            switch (state.status) {
                case 1:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                    UploadwithNoPrompt();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                    break;
            }

            function UploadwithNoPrompt() {
                //Do Nothing
            }

        } catch (err) {
            // Error supressed due to file overwrite wait
        }
    }
})(window);
```