# Disable Drag and Drop Functionality In Document Library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint we have default functionality that we can drag and drop documents in document library.

I want to disable drag and drop functionality. How can I do that?

I do not want to change in drag and drop's js that is reside in layout folder. Because it will effect on entire farm.

I want to change for specific site collection and only for document library.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82805/how-can-i-disable-the-document-library-drag-and-drop-function

Answer (score 1):

add this code in content editor web part:

```
<script>
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {

             g_uploadType = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
             SPDragDropManager.DragDropMode = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
        }, "DragDrop.js");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For disable Drag and Drop functionality add below code in "Script Editor".

Go to Setting -> Edit Page -> Insert -> Web Part -> Media and Content -> Script Editor and refresh the library.

```
<script>
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
             g_uploadType = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
             SPDragDropManager.DragDropMode = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
        }, "DragDrop.js");
</script>
```

That definitely works, I have tried.

Comment: I've seen this several places, but does not work on my SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I've also done the below to disable drag and drop:

1. add content editor web part to page
2. while Content Editor web part is selected, under "format text" in ribbon click edit source
3. add html
   ​​`<style> #ms-dnd-dropbox{ display: none !important; } </style>​​`