# Disable drag and drop option for multiple file uploader

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, development

These are the screenshots of multiple file uploader from the same SharePoint 2010 site. Some users are seeing the first and some are seeing the second one. Is it possible to disable the second view(drag and drop) by editing upload.aspx in the layouts folder?

[image]

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by editing the JS files.
read the below post, they enforcing the metadata when uploading the docuemnt and they talked about the disabling the drag and drop.

[How can I disable the Document Library drag and drop function?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82805/how-can-i-disable-the-document-library-drag-and-drop-function)

[Enforce Drag and Drop documents to apply metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata)