# $.getscript returning 'undefined'

Tags: 2013, javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get the script found under ['Enforce Drag and Drop documents to apply metadata'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata) to work and I am always getting an 'Undefined' error here:

`$.getScript("path_to_my_custom_js_file/DragDrop.Extended.js");`

I have tried several different locations and ways to write the URL but it always comes back with the same error.  Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is .js file located in `_layouts` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose .js file is located in a folder in `_layouts` folder, then use following code to load the file:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/FolderName/DragDrop.Extended.js
$.getScript(url);
```

Suppose the file is located in a folder in  dcoument library in root site collection named. Then this code can be used:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/LibraryUrl/Folder/DragDrop.Extended.js'
$.getScript(url);
```

**UPDATE**

If the library is in sub site and the page where you are running the script is also in that same subsite, then you can use:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.weAbsoluteUrl + '/LibraryUrl/Folder/DragDrop.Extended.js'
    $.getScript(url);
```

Comment: The .js file is located in the document library.  I tried your suggestion but it still gives me the undefined error.

Comment: Can you paste some code in the question. Also, is the document library in a root site collection or in a subsite?

Comment: Here is the part of the code that is giving me issues, along with the start of the script: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script unselectable="on">
 var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Document%20Library/Uploads/DragDrop.Extended.js'; 
 window.onload = function(){ 
 setTimeout(  function(){ 
 if(typeof UploadProgressFunc != "undefined"){
$.getScript(url);  
 } 
 }, 4000); 
 };

Comment: The Document Library is in a subsite.

Comment: And where is the page that is using this script. Is it also in the subsite?

Comment: Yes, it is on the same subsite.

Comment: @AllanSyvret, see my updated answer.

Comment: @ NadeemYousuf, It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Use Browser developer tools to check what url is getting created and then paste that url in separate browser window to check if you can browse the file

Comment: The browser can see the file correctly. I have even tried it with another script that launches correctly when launched directly from a Script Editor web part and it gives me the same error.

Comment: OK, now it does not give me the 'Undefined' error.  I changed some of the security settings and it seems to have solved that problem.  Now the rest of the script is not working but I'll post another question for that.  @NadeemYousuf, thanks for your help the var url helped.