# Drag and Drop show form

Tags: 2013, document-library, form, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to show the form(NewForm.aspx) when you do the drag and drop in a document library?

I already put some of the fields mandatory so the user won't be able to do the ckeck-in without fill those fields. But i want to know if i have other options here, like show the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata) a StackExchange thread on that. The short answer is there is no good solution in 2013. Your options:

1. Use default content type and required fields to prevent documents from being checked in (which you're doing).
2. Use a workflow to email people who haven't provided required
   information in a timely manner.
3. After detecting that a file is
   finished uploading add a layer yourself that prompts them for the
   data
4. Add an event handler on the back end to run certain actions when a new document of type x comes through and redirect to a page where they could be prompted.

Good luck.