# Force user for metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the following example and want to replicate this on my site. I want this box to pop-up when user uploads a file asking for certain metadata (some required, some optional). How do I enable this option?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: by this box, are you referring to the information box i.e. where the text says 'The document was uploade......'? Or the one in you marked in green color i.e. Name?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata

Comment: The gentleman who implemented this did not have coding knowledge. He did it without it by adding custom lists and then connecting them to the columns of library (as lookup columns) - I did this but the pop-up is not showing up after the upload though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an out of the box setting.

- Go to "Library Settings" from the ribbon.
- Go to "Advanced Settings".
- Check the "Yes" for the setting "Launch forms in a dialog".

[image]

- Save changes.

It opens a popup to update the metadata after you upload a document.

**EDIT:**

To open this popup you must have at least one mandatory field that shouldn`t have any default value.

Comment: I've tried this. Its not showing up. I have admin rights to the place where this is working and he don't have the Launch forms in dialog enabled. He don't even have content types enabled either. Not sure how he is forcing this. 

I've read elsewhere that you have to enable 'required fields' which I did and still the dialog is not showing up in my SharePoint site

Comment: Try removing default value for the mandatory fields.