# Raise a pop up when files is drag&drop

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

When user drag&drop the files in to the library. I want to raise a popup to collect additional info about the file and store it in library as column.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to store some additional info about the file in the column.

Comment: This might help. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata