# To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, script-webpart

I have the code from  [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/263484/84042) to my document library

The script basically opens the edit form when you Drag & Drop files into Document library.

The code seems to work fine, however I am getting this  pop up from Internet Explorer

> To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted. If you were making a purchase, you should click the Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. ... Otherwise, click Retry to display the webpage again

Maybe it can be something related to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc = 10000;
    function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
        if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc = _window.UploadProgressFunc;
            _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
            console.log('replaced dialog');
        } else if (maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc > 0) {
            maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc -= 100;
            setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


    function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
        _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
        var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
        switch (state.status) {
            case 1:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                break;
            case 3:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                break;
            case 4:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                OpenEditFormForLastItem(state);
                break;
            case 5:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                break;
        }

        function OpenEditFormForLastItem(state) {
            var caml = '';
            caml += "<View>";
            caml += "<Query>";
            caml += "<Where>";

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "<In>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                caml += "<Values>";
            } else {
                caml += "<Eq>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
            }

            state.files.forEach(function (file) {
                //only succesfull uploaded files that arent overwrites
                console.log(file);
                if (file.status === 5 /*&& !file.overwrite*/) {
                    caml += "<Value Type='File'>" + file.fileName + "</Value>";
                }
            }, this);

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "</Values>";
                caml += "</In>";
            } else {
                caml += "</Eq>";
            }

            caml += "</Where>";
            caml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            caml += "</Query>";
            caml += "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>";
            caml += "<RowLimit>500</RowLimit>";
            caml += "</View>";
            console.log(caml);

            var cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = cntxt.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.ctx.ListTitle);
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml(caml);
            var items = list.getItems(query);
            cntxt.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
            cntxt.load(items);
            cntxt.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                function openEditForItem() {
                    if (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                        var id = item.get_id();

                        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                        options.title = "Add File Metadata";
                        options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?ID=' + id;
                        options.autoSize = true;
                        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = openEditForItem;
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                    } else {
                        location.href = location.href;
                    }
                }
                openEditForItem();
            }, function (error, args) {
                    console.log("failed to get new uploaded items");
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(args);
                });
        }
    }
})(window);
</script>
```

And add the SharePoint site to to the Trusted Sites Zone and adjust the following Internet Explorer Security Setting:

1.Click Tools, then Internet Options

2.Select the Security Tab, then Trusted Sites

3.Click Custom Level

4.Select Enable under Automatic Prompting for Download

5.Click OK to save the setting

Comment: thank you. Adding the code seemed to fix the problem. Is there a way to modify the code so that when I upload multiple files via Drag&Drop options, the metadata dialog to show up only once and then all the files to get the same metadata?  It would be good to not fill the metadata for 10 files but instead  only do it once

Comment: can you please help me with the question above . would really appreciate it  @LZ_MSFT

Comment: The code only work for upload one file, if you upload multiple files, I suggest you use the OOTB "Upload" button.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use OOTB  "Upload" button becauseas far as I know if I use the upload button on sharepoint I can onlz select one file .

Comment: Click "Upload" button->"Files", to select multiple files, we can use Ctrl+ click file.

Comment: If you use the upload button, you cannot select mutiple files

Comment: Is it possible to modify the code so when I upload multiple files, the dialog box to only get shown once .